# Code Fails to Initialize Array of Strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to do something pretty simple: Establish a collection of 10 eight-character strings and assign a simple default value to each one. My code assigns the first string value, but then bombs with a segmentation fault. Code is below. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

   char *(names)[8];
   int i;
   char defstr[] = "none";

   *names = malloc(sizeof(char)*8*10);

   printf("%s\n",defstr);

   printf("defining\n");

   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      strcpy(names[i], defstr);
      printf("done with %d, string is %s\n", i, names[i]);
   }

   printf("now printing\n");

   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", names[i]);
   }
}
```

Output is

```
$> ./a.out
none
defining
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: You realize that the parentheses in `char *(names)[8];` are pointless, right? It's still equivalent to `char *(names[8]);`, an array of pointers, same as `char *names[8];`.

Comment: Why do you use brackets around names? `char *(names)[8]` what did you expect from this?

Comment: For one thing you have an array of size 8, but then loop 10 times through it.

Comment: @JamesElderfield hah!! beat you sir by 17 seconds. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh next time... :)

Comment: Not related to your issue, but to have a string hold 8 `char`s it needs to be 9 `char` long. Mind the `0`-terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *(names)[8];
```

declares an array of 8 pointers, the same as

```
char* names[8];
```

Then

```
*names = malloc(sizeof(char)*8*10);
```

sets the first of those pointers to point at an array of 80 characters.  The other 7 pointers are still uninitialized.

You seem to want a pointer to array, which would be

```
char (*names)[8];

names = malloc(10*sizeof(*names));
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters this declaration

```
char *(names)[8];
```

is equivalent to

```
char * names[8];
```

and declares an array of 8 pointers to char.

In this statement

```
*names = malloc(sizeof(char)*8*10);
```

the first element of the array (that is the element names[0]) is initialized by the address of the allocated memory. All other elements have undetermined  values.

Thus the following loop

for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      strcpy(names[i], defstr);
      printf("done with %d, string is %s\n", i, names[i]);
   }

is incorrect and results in undefined behaviour of the program because as it was said elements of the array with indices greater than 0 were not initialized.

What you mean is the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M   10
#define N   8

int main( void ) 
{
    char ( *names )[N];
    int i;
    char defstr[] = "none";

    names = malloc( sizeof( char[M][N] ) );

    printf( "%s\n", defstr );

    printf( "defining\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) 
    {
        strcpy(  names[i], defstr );
        printf( "done with %d, string is %s\n", i, names[i] );
    }

    printf("now printing\n");

    for ( i = 0;  i < M; i++ ) printf( "%s\n", names[i] );

    free( names );

    return 0;
}
```

In this program there is allocated dynamically a two-dimensional array of type `char [M][N]`. And this declaration

```
char ( *names )[N];
```

declares a pointer to an array of type `char[N]`.

Or the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M   10
#define N   8

int main( void ) 
{
    char * names[M];
    int i;
    char defstr[] = "none";

    printf( "%s\n", defstr );

    printf( "defining\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) 
    {
        names[i] = malloc( sizeof( char[N] ) );
        strcpy(  names[i], defstr );
        printf( "done with %d, string is %s\n", i, names[i] );
    }

    printf("now printing\n");

    for ( i = 0;  i < M; i++ ) printf( "%s\n", names[i] );

    for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) free( names[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

In this program there is declared a one-dimensional array of type `char * [M]` and each element of the array is initialized by the address of the allocated memory of type `char[N]`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the seg fault because you are overwritting allocated memory.

```
*names = malloc(sizeof(char)*8*10);
```

This line allocates 8 bytes of space for your first of 8 strings.

When i == 0, at:

```
strcpy(names[i], defstr);
```

You overwrite names[0] with defstr. But names[0] == *names (which you already allocated. Thus you just lost your allocation.

You must allocate all sections of your `**`.